# react-router-redux pass history to middleware

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, history.js, react-router-redux

I have the following files:

`configureStore.js`

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose, combineReducers } from 'redux'
import { routerReducer } from 'react-router-redux'
import middleware from './middleware'

export default (initialState) => createStore(
  combineReducers({
    ...
    router: routerReducer
  }),
  initialState,
  compose(applyMiddleware(...middleware))
)
```

`middleware.js`

```
import { routerMiddleware } from 'react-router-redux'

export default [
  ...
  routerMiddleware(/* How do I access history here? */) //<-- history
]
```

`index.js`

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { ConnectedRouter as Router } from 'react-router-redux'
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history'
import App from './App'
import configureStore from './configureStore'

const history = createBrowserHistory()

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={configureStore()}>
    <Router history={history}> //<-- history
      <App />
    </Router>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

Versions: "history": "4.7.2", "react-redux": "5.0.6", "react-router-redux": "5.0.0-alpha.8", "redux": "3.7.2"

So I must pass the history to the `<Router>` and to the `routerMiddleware()`. Is there an easy way to access the created history in `middleware.js`?

Comment: checkout https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5Knp04GZAj8&list=PL8vZpHuqa_hPpKUHFlyPkiI4MPexAMhvc&index=6 for an into to this.

Comment: The guy in the video does all in one file. Please read the question.

Answer (score 1):

A simple answer is no. But in JS everything is possible even if it's not a good thing.
You can pass in history to a function that then returns the router middleware.

```
// middleware.js

import { routerMiddleware } from "react-router-redux";


let createMiddleWare = ({history}) => { [
  routerMiddleware(history); //<-- history
])
```